# how can I compile javascript code in golang and get the detail error

Tags: go

I am using go language for a project. I need run a piece of js code in go. I know there is an package which is otto. My problem is that how I get the detail error message for the js code. For example:

```
src :=`
      abc = 2 + 
      console.log("The value of abc is " + abc)
 `
```

and when I do something let's say `compile(src)`.
Then I will get the error that: 
Miss something at second line and miss ';' at third line.
just like a compiler doing

I already try using the compile of otto before I post the problem, the returned error is nil. 
Using `func (self Otto) Run(src interface{}) (Value, error)` of otto for above code will return error, but if the code became

```
abc = 9
abc = 2 + 
console.log("The value of abc is " + abc)
```

for both `func (self Otto) Run(src interface{}) (Value, error)` and `func (self *Otto) Compile(filename string, src interface{}) (*Script, error)` the error are nil

Comment: None of your examples are errors in Javascript. Semicolons are not necessary in JS. Your example actually adds 2 + the result of console.log.

Comment: I bet your error during Run was "abc is not defined" because you tried to use abc in the console.log call before setting it. Not a syntax error because you might have defined it some other way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ding you for insufficient research. A simple Google of "golang otto" brought up [the Github page.](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto) With a pretty decent README.markdown for documentation. Read it.

Then you find out that Otto has

```
func (self *Otto) Compile(filename string, src interface{}) (*Script, error)
```

That is as good as it gets. Run that, see what you get in the returned error value.

[Also from the documentation:](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto#type-error)

```
type Error struct {
}

An Error represents a runtime error, e.g. a TypeError, a ReferenceError, etc.

func (err Error) Error() string

Error returns a description of the error

func (err Error) String() string

String returns a description of the error and a trace of where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I think you did not try what you said before you gave me the answer. I tried before I post the problem, with func (self *Otto) Compile(filename string, src interface{}) (*Script, error). The error is nil.